# Google Cloud Functions: require(...) is not a function

Tags: function, api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, speech

I am trying to deploy a Google Cloud function, I started by just adding the initial requirements to my index.js file:

```
// Import the Google Cloud client libraries
const nl = require('@google-cloud/language')();
const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech')();
const storage = require('@google-cloud/storage')();
```

But I get the following message when deploying:

```
Detailed stack trace: TypeError: require(...) is not a function
```

This only happens with the @google-cloud/speech and @google-cloud/language modules, the @google-cloud/storage module is loaded fine as a function (I tested by commenting the first two).

Any advise will be greatly appreciated.

Borrigan

Comment: Any news on this? Facing the same issue.

Comment: I figured out that at least the language package uses Environment Variables

Answer (score 14):

With reference to this Github [comment](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node/issues/2270#issuecomment-434773589), there was some changes in `google-cloud` v2 package

so you import packages such as:

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage({
  // config...
});
```

Comment: here is a link to the github release https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/releases/tag/v2.0.0

Answer (score 5):

Google cloud function are nodejs modules so the syntax is same as nodejs syntax.

Regarding your problem:

you have to write

```
const storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
```

(without () at the end of each statement)

So the correct declaration will be:

```
// Import the Google Cloud client libraries
const nl = require('@google-cloud/language');
const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');
const storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

It tells you that whatever you required is not a function and therefore can't be invoked with ()

if you look here : https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/language#using-the-client-library
you see a service object with multiple class returning functions is being returned, so you should set it up like this:

```
const nl = require('@google-cloud/language');
const language = new nl.LanguageServiceClient();
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow the new syntax below:

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const googleCloudStorage = new Storage({
    projectId: 'your-project-id',
    keyFilename: 'path-to-json-config-file'
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thank you for your willingness to help! I would recommend you spend a little more time creating your answer, however. Adding some detail to help clarify what your code does and why you're doing it that way will help make your answer stand out.